# setInterval and React functional components

Tags: reactjs

I have a question about using `setInterval` inside functional components and the behaviour of functions inside the aforementioned components.

I have the following piece of code (stripped and simplified to show the problem only):

```
let timerInterval;

const ModuleAssignedUtils = (props) => {
  const [timer, setTimer] = useState(0);

  updateTimer = () => {
    let timer_tmp;
    if (timer <= 0) {
      clearInterval(timerInterval)
      setTimer(0)
      setButtonPressed(false);
    }
    else {
      timer_tmp = timer - 1;
      setTimer(timer_tmp)
    }
  }

  const locateVehicle = () => {
    if (!buttonPressed) {
      setButtonPressed(true);
      setTimer(10);
      timerInterval = setInterval(() => {
        updateTimer();
      }, 1000);
    }
  }

  return (
    ...

    <ButtonContainer timer={timer}
                     noButtonLoading
                     onEvent={locateVehicle} />
    ...
    )

}
```

This code actually does the job. User presses the button, which triggers the function `locateVehicle`, which in turn sets the timer in state to 10 and then starts the interval with the `updateTimer` function.

However, as soon as I change the `updateTimer` definition to include `const` or `function`, this piece of code stops working. The state is set, but `updateTimer` is always called with `timer = 0`, so it doesn't know that the state has been changed.

I struggle to understand the difference between declaring the function without any proper declaration and actually declaring it properly with `const` or `function` keywords. Would appreciate a lot if someone could explain me this behaviour.

P.S. I have since refactored this component and am using `useInterval` custom hook as suggested by Dan Abramov, so everything is fine. Just trying to understand the logic behind the behaviour in this particular case.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it stopped working is that your context (the good old `this`) is not set up.

When you write down an arrow function expressions such as your `updateTimer`, it automatically binds up your cotext, just like using the `bind` [function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind).

You will encounter with the same issue in case of function declaration inside the setInterval method.

Comment: If I understand you answer correctly, then it should be working if I did ```const updateTimer = () => {....}```, which doesn't work.

Comment: Actually no :)
Using the const assigning the arrow function to a variable (functions are first-class citizen in javascript), the context is not assigned here at all.